# add 1 value to new column and perform operation on it with other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, operation

I have a dataframe,

```
x     y     z    new_col
Nan   NaN   Nan    1
1     2     3      4
2     3     4      20
2     1     3      60
```

So basically formula is,
1 of new_col that we set first 1 * (1 + 3), then 4 * (1 + 4), then 20 * (1+3),  so on..
How should I first create a new column (new_col) and then add 1 at first row, then perform calculation.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand the formula. Please include the expected output and clarify what you're trying to do. How does the formula relate to `x`, `y` , `z` given in the DF?

Comment: Expected output is the new column (new_col), create another column new_col and make it first value to 1, then consider that 1 for second value of new_col, then consider previous value for third value of new_col, so on.

Comment: I think I see it: the expected output *is* included.  The formula for column "new-col", row `n`, is `new_col[n] = new_col[n-1] * (1 + z[n])`

Comment: @Prune I thought of the same thing.

Comment: @BarsmansvapsFriends: what have you tried?  There should be examples for cumulative sum that you could adapt, and perhaps a handful for cumulative product.

Comment: @prune I think you might be right. So `x` and `y` are redundant.

Comment: I tried this, df['new_col'] = np.NaN
df.ix[1, 'new_col'] = 1
df['new_col'].shift()*(1+df['z'])

Answer (score 1):

### `cumprod`

```
df.assign(new_col=df.z.fillna(0).add(1).cumprod())

     x    y    z  new_col
0  NaN  NaN  NaN      1.0
1  1.0  2.0  3.0      4.0
2  2.0  3.0  4.0     20.0
3  2.0  1.0  3.0     80.0
```

Attempt to preserve dtype

```
df.assign(new_col=df.z.fillna(0, downcast='infer').add(1).cumprod())

     x    y    z  new_col
0  NaN  NaN  NaN        1
1  1.0  2.0  3.0        4
2  2.0  3.0  4.0       20
3  2.0  1.0  3.0       80
```

---

### With Numba

The point of this is to show how to perform a linear path dependent calculation.  Numba is very fast and if the calculation has a time complexity of O(N) then you don't have to be afraid of using this loop in Numba.

If you don't have `numba` installed and don't want to install it, just remove the `@njit` decorator.

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def f(a):
    out = np.zeros_like(a)
    out[0] = 1
    for i, x in enumerate(a[1:], 1):
        out[i] = out[i-1] * (1 + x)
    return out

df.assign(new_col=f(df.z.values))

     x    y    z  new_col
0  NaN  NaN  NaN      1.0
1  1.0  2.0  3.0      4.0
2  2.0  3.0  4.0     20.0
3  2.0  1.0  3.0     80.0
```

---

With `int`

```
df.assign(new_col=f(df.z.fillna(0).astype(int).values))

     x    y    z  new_col
0  NaN  NaN  NaN        1
1  1.0  2.0  3.0        4
2  2.0  3.0  4.0       20
3  2.0  1.0  3.0       80
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a much simpler solution, this will be helpful.

You can just create a new column named "new_column" and initialize all the values to 1 (since the first value should be 1).

```
df['new_column'] = 1
```

Then, you can use a for loop to iterate through the rows and update the new column values according to your formula.

```
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'new_column'] = df['new_column'][i-1] * (1 + df['Z'][i])
```